# xcode 6.3.2 - simulator wrong screen size

Tags: simulator, screen-size, xcode6.3.2

---

I have very weird bug with simulator in xcode 6.3.2 yosimite 10.10

when I open simulator\run app in it
sometimes it's opens  normal simulator, and sometimes... well look at picture below
it's like simulator screen dimensions are different from those appear on actual screen.

from my checks it has nothing to do with window scaling, or device (iphone5, 5s, 6 etc...)

Any ideas?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, after many other checks there is
some very interesting thing I've found about simulator's layout engine.
Even when it opens normally it gives wrong size calculation BUT at the same time preserves initial aspect ratio

I've created 2 objects: blueSquare 
and redRect. 
as for console - the width & height calculated correctly

[image]

but look how the redRect drawn on the actual screen:

[image]

instead of been half width size, it's even larger...
and when I shrink it even smaller (quarter)
it's drawn a lit bigger then an actual half

[image]

****Conclusion****
In my opinion it's just another annoying bug of xCode6.3.2 (stable) version
and hope the next xCode will be more stable...